# How to find 5 digit number in a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I just need to get a 5 digits number that is separated by a space. 
The 5 digits number can be anywhere in the varchar.

Example: I have a varchar column with this various data in SQL 2008 table

```
travel visa 34322 LLL001
Coffee 34332 Jakarta 
FDR001 34312 Taxi cost cash
taxi cash 34321
34556 eating dinner with customer
eating dinner 34256 with customer
visa cost 34221 REF773716637366
```

the 5 digits number can be anywhere separated by a space
what is best to extract this?

```
34322
34332
34312
34556
34256
34221
```

Thanks

Row like this should return blank

```
Visa refNbr 778738878
```

Tried the following  with no luck yet

```
SELECT  pjtran.tr_comment 
,substring(pjtran.tr_comment,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',pjtran.tr_comment),5)
,Left(SubString(pjtran.tr_comment, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', pjtran.tr_comment), 50),PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(pjtran.tr_comment, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', pjtran.tr_comment), 50) + 'X')-1)
,len(pjtran.tr_comment)-len(replace(pjtran.tr_comment,' ',''))
```

I think I need to use a combination of counting the number of space in the varchar. and the above. but I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Is there ever a situation where there are multiple numbers in a string?

Comment: Check out the function at this link http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/ using a udf.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375133/how-do-i-extract-part-of-a-string-in-t-sql

Comment: Basically I just need to get a 5 digits number that is separated by a space. If there is a duplicate 5 digits number in the varchar, I just get the first 5 digits. eg: "taxi price 34523 33564" then I just get 34523. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
 select substring(tr_comment, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', tr_comment), 5) as zip5
```

If you want to consider that it might be at the end of the string:

```
 select substring(tr_comment, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %', tr_comment + ' '), 5
                 ) as zip5
```

Answer (score 0):

use this, this may help you

```
 select SUBSTRING(tr_comment, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', tr_comment), 5) as zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try It

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_ExtractNumberFromString]
(
    @pInputString VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @OutputString varchar(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @string varchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @start INT
    DECLARE @end INT
    DECLARE @len INT

    SET @string=@pInputString
    --SET @string = 'the22478hollies12345TestAddressDr.789324-#345'
    SET @string = replace(@string, ' ' , '')

    WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@string) <> 0
    BEGIN   
        SET @len = len(@string)
    --  PRINT @len

        set @start = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@string)
    --  PRINT @start

        SET @end= PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',SUBSTRING(@string,@start,@len-@start))
    --  PRINT @end

        IF @end=0
            BEGIN
                SET @end=@len-@start
                SET @OutputString=SUBSTRING(@string,@start,@end+1)+'-'+@OutputString
                BREAK
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                SET @OutputString=SUBSTRING(@string,@start,@end-1)+'-'+@OutputString
                SET @string=SUBSTRING(@string,@end+@start-1,@len-@end)
            END 

        --PRINT @string

        --PRINT @Output
        --PRINT '---------------------'
    END

    IF LEN(@OutputString)>0
        SET @OutputString=LEFT(@OutputString,LEN(@OutputString)-1) 
    --PRINT @OutputString

    RETURN @OutputString
END
```