# Use part of VARCHAR column as date in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table where the varchar column `CREATED_BY` has the data in the format
`USER - dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm`.

I'm trying to do data migration and need to get records where the created date is greater than a certain date, but the format of the column makes this difficult, so

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE -- last part of CREATED_BY > SOMEDATE
```

Comment: `WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME,CREATED_BY,103) >= somedate`

Comment: @Lamak: This will raise a `conversion failed...` error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled it doesn't for me

Comment: it did for me... [in fiddle also,](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/5292) and also in [2014 fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/5931).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah, didn't see the `USER` part of the string

Comment: If it literally always has "USER - " in it, you can nest the replace() function to ignore that part of the string.

Comment: @Lamak that's OK, I didn't see the time portion at first, so I guess we are even :-)

Comment: @TabAlleman Seriously? I wasn't even thinking about the possibility of that USER - not be a placeholder for a user name or id....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract part of a string in t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375133/how-do-i-extract-part-of-a-string-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since the `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` format has a fixed length, you can use the `RIGHT` function to extract the data part from your string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(CREATED_BY, 16), 103) > somedate
```

Comment: Didn't see the time portion, fixed the length

Comment: Note that you still may have to fix some data because it was incorrectly entered and even that portion is not a valid date..

Comment: This one worked best. I only needed the date portion so I used the `SUBSTRING` method instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the date from the string:

```
WHERE cast(reverse ( substring ( reverse ( @string  ) , 1 , 16 ) )  as datetime) > somedate
```

Comment: Why is this being voted down? OP has asked how to extract a date from a string containing other text as well.

Comment: Good question. It is a rather cumbersome way to extract the right part of the string when you have the built-in `right` function, though I don't see a reason to downvote for that.